# Why name 'HaarCascade' is not defined?

Tags: python, opencv, jupyter, face-recognition, facenet

```py
import cv2
import os
os.sys.path
from os import listdir
from PIL import Image

from numpy import asarray
from numpy import expand_dims
import pickle

folder="data_test_deteksi"
database = {}

for filename in listdir(folder):

    path = folder + filename
    gbr1 = cv2.imread(folder + filename)
    
    wajah = HaarCascade.detectMultiScale(gbr1,1.1,4)
    
    if len(wajah)>0:
        x1, y1, width, height = wajah[0]         
    else:
        x1, y1, width, height = 1, 1, 10, 10
        
    x1, y1 = abs(x1), abs(y1)
    x2, y2 = x1 + width, y1 + height
    
    gbr = cv2.cvtColor(gbr1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    gbr = Image.fromarray(gbr)                  # konversi dari OpenCV ke PIL
    gbr_array = asarray(gbr)
    
    face = gbr_array[y1:y2, x1:x2]                        
    
    face = Image.fromarray(face)                       
    face = face.resize((160,160))
    face = asarray(face)
    
    face = face.astype('float32')
    mean, std = face.mean(), face.std()
    face = (face - mean) / std
    
    face = expand_dims(face, axis=0)
    signature = MyFaceNet.predict(face)
    
    database[os.path.splitext(filename)[0]]=signature
```

Comment: Self explained: There is no variable call HaarCascade

Comment: question should be closed because it's due to a typo (well, you know, typo)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing named as `HaarCascade` in opencv, you need to use `cv2.CascadeClassifier`. First download `haarcascade` xml file and then pass the path of that file like this

`face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')`